# constructing Page URL that i can reach after inserting an item number into search box

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

I'm writing a python script to **scrape** an online shopping website
every item on this website has an item number and after inserting an item number into search box I'm redirected to item page
when I looked to the URL of this page there was no clue about the item number in this URL _ so I can replace it with any number after that so I can go directly to the item page without going first to website portal_
any clue how to construct this URL?
is it a general case or it depends on every website?
say my website is [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/) so to reach this page [searching for cisco 262 on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=cisco%20%20262&_sacat=0) there are 2 ways:

- open [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/) and then inserting cisco 262 into the search box
- use this URL  [cisco 262 search result on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=cisco%20%20262&_sacat=0) 
  as we can see from URL we can replace "cisco++262" with what we want to search for so we can  go directly to search result without going first to the main page of eBay and inserting what we want to search for into the search box 
  my question here is it's not always clear in the URL where you can put what you want to search for so you can go directly to its page
  so is there any way to know how to construct URL if it's not clear.
  Update
  here is the base [url](https://nextgen.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fhome.do) of website I want to **scrape**
  and here is the page [url](https://nextgen.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fchange_request.do%3Fsys_id%3Dafc5154ddb923b805f40118e3b96192e%26sysparm_stack%3D%26sysparm_view%3D) after inserting this value "CHG2020324" into its the search box
  another [url](https://nextgen.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fchange_request.do%3Fsys_id%3D17d9d0addb6a73481907d06b6896192a%26sysparm_stack%3D%26sysparm_view%3D) after inserting this "CHG2022230" into the search box
  so as you can see there is no clue where to put item number so we can reconstruct url ...any help with url inspecting or constructing.

Comment: I don't believe anybody can understand what the question is. Please take some time and rewrite your text.

Comment: There is no standard that says how a [SKU number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit) should be constructed. You will need to scrape search results first to find out those ids.

Comment: @ipaleka I edited the question, hope I could make it clearer

Comment: If it's about single site then you'll probably be able to find the majority of variations by testing. For undefined site you can't know the actual implementation of the backend's url dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to go straight to the search result pages using a series of search strings. If so, then - at least in the case of ebay (if will likely be different for each site) - you can use f-strings together with a base url to achieve that:

```
base_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw='
search_strings = ['ryzen', 'cisco 262'] #examples of a single word and phrase search strings

for srchstr in search_strings:
    src = srchstr.replace(' ','+') #note the ebay represents a phrase as "word1+word2"; other sites will do it differently
    print(f'{base_url}"{src}"')
```

Output:

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw="ryzen"
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw="cisco+262"
```

And these take to the search result pages for the respective search strings.

Comment: EBay is just for clarification, and the intended website that I really want to scrape i can only access via Vpn that's why I don't put its url.